# JQuery on fadeout command

Tags: jquery

I would like to on fade out, reset the selected value to "1"
Using the coding format starting with JQuery
For example:

```
jQuery("select[name='wpcf-it-software-jobs']").prepend('<option value="">- select     
-</option>');
```

And my html is as normal, with value and option tag around it.

Thank you

I did try

```
 jQuery("select[name='wpcf-it-software-jobs']").fadeOut(function(){.val('<option value="">- select     
-</option>');
```

No luck in trying that.

UPDATE
There is actually a code I used following the above .prepend code

```
jQuery("select[name='wpcf-it-software-jobs']")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

I have no idea what is it but it is provided by support team. Any link of these two?

Comment: `jQuery("select[name='wpcf-it-software-jobs']").fadeOut(function(){$(this).val(1);});` ???

Comment: fadeOut(function(){.val(' -> syntax?! fix your code in the question pls.

Comment: @mightyuhu please drag the cursor to see the whole code tq

Comment: @mightyuhu, that code should not be fixed since it shows an incorrect attempt at solving the problem, which makes the question on-topic (and A.Wolff's comment is the answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the `value` of the select to nothing (which is the value I assume you're setting for the `- select option -` option). jQuery should change the drop down to select the item which has the matching value.

```
jQuery("select[name='wpcf-it-software-jobs']").fadeOut(400, function() {
    // Fadeout Complete, so change the selected item to the first one
    $(this).val('');
});
```

Comment: referring to my question, i have give '<option value="">- select     
-</option>'); which gives jquery a clue that it should ammend the <option> tag,correct me if im worng, but the code u provided does not have such? will it work?

Comment: @CheongDMunPong try it, it should do, assuming the value of the option with ```- select -``` is ```""```.

Answer (score 0):

Use option.eq(1) and prop('selected'), true) where 1 is index (0, 1, 2,....)

```
jQuery(function() {
   jQuery("select[name='wpcf-it-software-jobs']").fadeOut(800, function() {
      $(this).fadeIn();
      $("select[name='wpcf-it-software-jobs'] option:eq(1)").prop('selected', true)

  });

});
```

Or you can use

```
  $("select[name='wpcf-it-software-jobs'] option[value='1']").attr("selected", "selected");
```